# How to make Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) Inverter using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I have a VSI SPWM Inverter Project, but my supervisor ask me to upgrade it to a VFD Inverter. I've found a code about how to generate 3 phase SPWM in this [article](http://www.eprojectszone.com/how-to-generate-three-phase-spwm-signal-with-arduino/), and i've tried the code. The output signal is great. But i need to improve the code to VFD code with range frequency 0-100 Hz. I've found a reference about VFD from this [one](https://github.com/carneeki/OpenVFD/blob/master/software/OpenVFD.ino) and tried to modify the SPWM code, but failed. Could anyone help me to improve the code, please? Here is the SPWM code..

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
int x=0;
int y=0;
int z=0;
int OK=0;
int OK1=0;
int OK2=0;
int OK3=0;
int OK4=0;
int sinPWM[]={1,2,5,7,10,12,15,17,19,22,24,27,30,32,34,37,39,42,
44,47,49,52,54,57,59,61,64,66,69,71,73,76,78,80,83,85,88,90,92,94,97,99,
101,103,106,108,110,113,115,117,119,121,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,
148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,169,171,173,175,177,178,180,182,184,185,187,188,190,192,193,
195,196,198,199,201,202,204,205,207,208,209,211,212,213,215,216,217,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,
228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,237,238,239,240,240,241,242,242,243,243,244,244,245,245,246,246,
247,247,247,248,248,248,248,249,249,249,249,249,255,255,255,255,249,249,249,249,249,248,
248,248,248,247,247,247,246,246,245,245,244,244,243,243,242,242,241,240,240,239,238,237,237,236,235,234,
233,232,231,230,229,228,227,226,225,224,223,222,221,220,219,217,216,215,213,212,211,209,208,207,205,204,
202,201,199,198,196,195,193,192,190,188,187,185,184,182,180,178,177,175,173,171,169,168,166,164,162,160,
158,156,154,152,150,148,146,144,142,140,138,136,134,132,130,128,126,124,121,119,117,115,113,110,108,106,
103,101,99,97,94,92,90,88,85,83,80,78,76,73,71,69,66,64,61,59,57,54,52,49,47,44,42,39,37,34,32,30,
27,24,22,19,17,15,12,10,7,5,2,1};

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);

cli();// stop interrupts
TCCR0A=0;//reset the value
TCCR0B=0;//reset the value
TCNT0=0;//reset the value
//0b allow me to write bits in binary
TCCR0A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR0B=0b00000001; //no prescaler



TCCR2A=0;//reset the value
TCCR2B=0;//reset the value
TCNT2=0;//reset the value
//0b allow me to write bits in binary
TCCR2A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR2B=0b00000001; //no prescaler

TCCR3A=0;//reset the value
TCCR3B=0;//reset the value
TCNT3=0;//reset the value
//0b allow me to write bits in binary
TCCR3A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR3B=0b00000001; //no prescaler
TCCR1A=0;//reset the value
TCCR1B=0;//reset the value
TCNT1=0;//reset the value
OCR1A=509;// compare match value
TCCR1B=0b00001001; //WGM12 bit is 1 for CTC mode and no prescaler

TIMSK1 |=(1 << OCIE1A);// enable interrupts

sei();//stop interrupts
}
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){// interrupt when timer 1 match with OCR1A value
if(i>313 && OK==0){// final value from vector for pin 13
i=0;// go to first value of vector
OK=1;//enable pin 4
}
if(i>313 && OK==1){// final value from vector for pin 4
i=0;//go to firs value of vector
OK=0;//enable pin 13
}
x=sinPWM[i];// x take the value from vector corresponding to position i(i is zero indexed)
i=i+1;// go to the next position
if(OK==0){
OCR0B=0;//make pin 4 0
OCR0A=x;//enable pin 13 to corresponding duty cycle
}
if(OK==1){
OCR0A=0;//make pin 13 0
OCR0B=x;//enable pin 4 to corresponding duty cycle
}

if ((i==209) || OK1==1){//if i equal with 209 enable second signal
OK1=1;//mantain if function
if(j>313 && OK2==0){// final value from vector for pin 10
j=0;// go to first value of vector
OK2=1;//enable pin 9
}
if(j>313 && OK2==1){// final value from vector for pin 9
j=0;//go to firs value of vector
OK2=0;//enable pin 10
}
y=sinPWM[j];// y take the value from vector corresponding to position j(j is zero indexed)
j=j+1;// go to the next position
if(OK2==0){
OCR2B=0;//make pin 9 0
OCR2A=y;//enable pin 10 to corresponding duty cycle
}
if(OK2==1){
OCR2A=0;//make pin 10 0
OCR2B=y;//enable pin 9 to corresponding duty cycle
}
}
if ((j==209) || OK3==1){//if j equal with 209 enable third signal
OK3=1;//mantain if function
if(k>313 && OK4==0){// final value from vector for pin 5
k=0;// go to first value of vector
OK4=1;//enable pin 2
}
if(k>313 && OK4==1){// final value from vector for pin 2
k=0;//go to firs value of vector
OK4=0;//enable pin 5
}
z=sinPWM[k];// z take the value from vector corresponding to position k(k is zero indexed)
k=k+1;// go to the next position
if(OK4==0){
OCR3B=0;//make pin 2 0
OCR3A=z;//enable pin 5 to corresponding duty cycle
}
if(OK4==1){
OCR3A=0;//make pin 5 0
OCR3B=z;//enable pin 2 to corresponding duty cycle
}
}
}
void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Most, like I, in this corner of stackexchange.com (Arduinos) are likely thinking you mean Vacuum Florescent Display.  Not Variable Frequency Drive. You may get more responses if you explain this in your title.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll edit the title..

Comment: i have sum code please visit my https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=645080.msg4363292#msg4363292